# Calculate feature count based on a certain field in arcade

Tags: arcade, arcgis-enterprise

I am new to arcade. I have a hosted feature layer in my portal in which I have a field named district and it has records like A, A, A, B, C, C. I essentially want to get total count of A, B, C and display it as label.

On researching on this I came across this post : [Calculating feature count of attribute type using arcade in ArcGIS Online](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/355050/calculating-feature-count-of-attribute-type-using-arcade-in-arcgis-online) in which the user is trying to do the same thing and, it has been achieved using Filter and Count function.

Since, I am on 10.9.1 I won't be able to use Filter function hence, I tried the following code which doesn't use filter function.

```
var countf = 0
//var test = $feature.districts

for (var i = 0; i < $feature.districts; i++){
    if (i == $feature.districts[i]){
        countf = countf + 1
    }
}
```

The code is not giving me any error however, am not getting correct result. I believe I am missing out on the syntax.

Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: Suggest you study the help file on [For](https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/guide/loops/#for) because the condition `i < $feature.districts` makes no sense- is a number smaller than a word???